# ORACLE query using NOT IN too many values

Tags: oracle

I have an `Oracle` query below:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
WA_GA_TBL_ACTIVITY A,
WA_GA_TBL_USERS U
WHERE
A.USERID_FK = U.USERID AND
(A.GROUPID_FK = 'GR0001' OR U.GROUPID_FK = 'GR0001') AND
A.USERID_FK != 'US0007' AND
(A.ACTIVITYID) NOT IN(SELECT ACTIVITYID_FK FROM WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSACTIVITY 
WHERE USERID_FK = 'US0007'
```

The first logic to check in `WA_GA_TBL_ACTIVITY` when userid != `US0007`.
And now I want to get user details in `NOT IN`:

```
NOT IN(SELECT ACTIVITYID_FK FROM WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSACTIVITY 
WHERE USERID_FK = 'US0007'
```

When userid_fk = `US0007`

I tried like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
WA_GA_TBL_ACTIVITY A,
WA_GA_TBL_USERS U
WHERE
A.USERID_FK = U.USERID AND
(A.GROUPID_FK = 'GR0001' OR U.GROUPID_FK = 'GR0001') AND
A.USERID_FK != 'US0007' AND
(A.ACTIVITYID) NOT IN(SELECT S.USERID, S.DATEADDED, W.ACTIVITYID_FK FROM WA_GA_TBL_USERS S, WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSACTIVITY 
W
WHERE S.USERID = W.USERID_FK AND W.USERID_FK = 'US0007')
```

got error:

```
ORA-00913: too many values
```

Sample Data

TABLE WA_GA_TBL_ACTIVITY

```
ACTIVITYID | ACTIVITYNAME | USERID_FK | ACTIVITYDATE | GROUPID_FK
001        | add new user | US0001    | 4/6/2017     | GR0001
```

TABLE WA_GA_TBL_USERS

```
USERID | USERNAME | DATEADDED
US0001 | testuser1| 4/6/2017
US0007 | testuser2| 4/6/2017
```

TABLE WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSACTIVITY

```
ACTIVITYID_FK | USERID_FK
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The `too many values` error is being caused by that you are using `NOT IN` with a subquery which returns multiple columns.  As to what you are actually trying to do, that is another story.

Comment: Is there any possible to do the query? Maybe query function? Because I need to get the details of user from that NOT IN query

Comment: Can you show us sample data?  I'm afraid without that I would only be guessing here.

Comment: Do you really need `S.USERID, S.DATEADDED` in the select clause of `not in`?

Comment: @Utsav I suspect the OP thinks he needs to select those columns in order  to use them in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I can't give you the sample data due to that query is error. The logic is when query the data: 1. Query the data when USERID != 'US0007', 2. After first query then continue the query NOT IN when USERID_FK = 'US0007' and I want to get the details of user from NOT IN query

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes correct

Comment: what we mean by sample data is that you give some rows from all the tables used and your expected output based on that. Without it we could only be guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns in projection of the `IN` sub-query must match the number referenced by the predicate. You get the `ORA-00913: too many values` error because `(A.ACTIVITYID)` does not match `(SELECT S.USERID, S.DATEADDED, W.ACTIVITYID_FK` .

All you need to do is correlate

```
SELECT
       *
FROM
WA_GA_TBL_ACTIVITY A,
WA_GA_TBL_USERS U
WHERE
A.USERID_FK = U.USERID AND
(A.GROUPID_FK = 'GR0001' OR U.GROUPID_FK = 'GR0001') AND
A.USERID_FK != 'US0007' AND
(A.ACTIVITYID) NOT IN (SELECT W.ACTIVITYID_FK 
                       FROM WA_GA_TBL_USERS S, 
                           WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSACTIVITY W
                           WHERE S.USERID = W.USERID_FK 
                           AND W.USERID_FK = 'US0007')
```

It seems like you could simplify that subquery to this

```
 (SELECT W.ACTIVITYID_FK 
   FROM WA_GA_TBL_ACCESSACTIVITY W
   WHERE W.USERID_FK = 'US0007')
```

but you know your business logic better than I do.